# Completely exlude subdomain with Varnish

Tags: caching, varnish, sqlbuddy

Scenario:
I have an Apache/Varnish setup with a number of different subdomains. Every subdomain has its own VirtualHost-file in sites-enabled but all run in the same Wordpress installation. Except for one: sqlbuddy.mydomain.com, which is a standalone site for Sqlbuddy (web-based SQL management).

Problems:
Varnish works flawlessly with all sites except sqlbuddy. Sometimes I can't access it at all and get the error "Error 503 Backend fetch failed". Sometimes I can access it but get the same error when I try to log in. Sometimes nothing at all happens when I try to log in. Sometimes the login succeeds but I get error when I try to do something.

What I want/tried:
This site does not need caching so I want Varnish to completely ignore it.

This is what I've tried (at the top of my vcl_recv):

```
if (req.http.host == "sqlbuddy.mydomain.com" && req.url == "/") {
return (pass);
}
```

and different variations of it (without the req.url, return (pipe); etc) but I still get the errors.
I've also tried putting the VirtualHost on a different port to bypass Varnish, but it seems that sqlbuddy wont listen to it.

Otherwise I use this VCL:
https://gist.github.com/nadirlc/46987b42447cf8e3be79
and the VirtualHosts listens to 127.0.0.1:8008.

Is there some other way of doing it with Varnish?

Let me know if more info is needed or I've missed something obvious. I'm not exactly the best there is when it comes to Varnish.

Comment: When you say "standalone", does that mean it's on a different port or is it being served out of the same apache instance?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a regular expression matching instead with ~

```
if (req.http.host ~ "sqlbuddy.mydomain.com") {
return (pass);
}
```

or even

```
if (req.http.host ~ "sqlbuddy") {
return (pass);
}
```